# I am trying to build custom loss function in pytorch, but I am getting nan loss and accuracy is not improving

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, cross-entropy

```
class crossentropy(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(crossentropy, self).__init__()

    def forward(self, y_1, y):
        m = nn.Softmax(dim=1)
        output = m(y_1)
        loss = -1.0*torch.sum(y*torch.log(output))
        l = torch.mean(loss)
        return l
```

Comment: There are two possible cases, either some elements of y or y_1 are NaN, or elements of output are too close to 0

Comment: In any case, you should use LogSoftmax instead of taking the log of the softmax, that may avoid the 2nd case

Comment: `m` should be created in `__init__` as `self.m = ...`.

Comment: Have you tried replacing your `crossentropy` class with the standard classes and seeing if that still doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

It is probable that using `LogSoftmax` instead of `Softmax` then `log` should solve this issue (probably caused by the log giving infinite values to near-0 results of softmax, due to numerical error)

Comment: class crossentropy(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self,m=0):
        super(crossentropy, self).__init__()
        self.m = m
    def forward(self, y_1, y):
        m = self.m
        m = nn.LogSoftmax()
        output = m(y_1)
        loss = -1.0*torch.sum(y*output)
        l = torch.mean(loss)
        return l

Comment: It still gives the same error, I tried removing log  and it gives good accuracy score and negative loss

Comment: Still Nan ? what is the output of the LogSoftmax ?